# Is Kashyapa gotra same as Koushika gotra?

Tags: mahabharata, gotra

In the Mahabharata Kaushika gotra is mentioned and kashyapa gotra might have mentioned. Are the two gotras same?

Comment: Don't write entire title or body in Caps.

Comment: How is this related to Mahabharata?

Answer (score 5):

In Hindu society, Gotra broadly refers to people who are descendants in an unbroken male lineage from a common male ancestor or patrilineage.

Kashyapa was one of the eight original gotras (clans) of the Brahmins, being derived from Kashyapa, the name of a rishi (hermit) whom they believed to have heard the Veda.

On other hand, Brahmins belonging to the Vishvamitra Gotra/Kaushika Gotra consider Brahmarshi Vishvamitra as their ancestor. As Brahmarshi Vishvamitra was also known as  Rishi 'Kaushika'[He is the son of the king Kusha.]

So Kashyapa gotra is **NOT** the same as Kaushika gotra.